# Передать символ # через telegram API (python)

Tags: python, requests, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить через тг бота сообщение содержащее "#", но отправляется только текст до этого символа

```
mes = 'startText#endText'
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chatId}&text={mes}'
requests.get(url)
```

Отправляет только startText

Answer (score 4):

Всё дело в специфике [кодирования параметров в URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL), а именно: тебе нужно экранировать символ `#` следующим образом:

> Преобразование происходит в два этапа: сначала каждый символ кириллицы кодируется в UTF-8 в последовательность из двух байтов, а затем каждый байт этой последовательности записывается в шестнадцатеричном представлении с предшествующим знаком процента (%)

Короче говоря, вот так: `mes = 'startText%23endText'`

```py
mes = 'startText%23endText'
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chatId}&text={mes}'
requests.get(url)
```